# How to render --- as emdash in react-markdown? and ellipsis ...? and opened / closed quotes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown

I would like to know how I can render ... (three dots) as … (ellipsis) in **react-markdown**. The same for --- (three dashes) as — (emdash) and opened / closed quotes "text" as “text”.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of `react-markdown`?

Comment: The last one: react-markdown 9.0.1

Comment: Then I'd look at https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-textr.

Comment: The given example of remark-textr is at backend, and I need to use it at frontend (react)... I wouldn't mind to change react-markdown for another markdown library if it is necessary... but I need to use smartypants. How can I have a secure markdown with smartypants in frontend (react)?

Comment: The example being for a backend program doesn't matter, since [`react-markdown` supports `remark` plugins](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown?tab=readme-ov-file#use-a-plugin).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) was right. The best option to fix that is with textr. Here is my code with emdash, ellipsis and quotes:

```
import Markdown from "react-markdown";
import remarkTextr from "remark-textr";
import {smartypants} from "../constants";

const Comp = () => {

return(<Markdown remarkPlugins={[[remarkTextr, {plugins: [smartypants]}]]}>"This is emdash ---"</Markdown>);

}

export default Comp;
```

And in other TS file (constants file, see import above):

```
export function smartypants(input: string) {
    const ellipsisReplaced: string = input.replace(/\.\.\./g, "…");
    const emDashReplaced: string = ellipsisReplaced.replace(/---/g, "—");
    const curlyQuotesReplaced: string = emDashReplaced.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, "“$1”");
    return curlyQuotesReplaced;
}
```

It works like a charm!! Thanks a lot, AKX.